# Insert data into the next row

Tags: excel, vba

I insert data from my UserForm into my Excel sheet.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OIL_")
Dim fn_lastrow As Long
fn_lastrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))
'Validações-----------------------------------------------------
If Me.txtID.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Insira um ID!", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
If Me.txtDesc.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Insira uma Descrição!", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
'---------------------------------------------------------------
If fn_lastrow + 1 <= 15 Then fn_lastrow = 15 Else fn_lastrow = fn_lastrow + 1
sh.Cells(fn_lastrow, 2).Value = Me.txtID.Value
sh.Cells(fn_lastrow, 11).Value = Me.txtDesc.Value
sh.Cells(fn_lastrow, 29).Value = Me.txtData.Value

End Sub
```

The problem is, when I insert other data it substitutes the previous data inserted.

This is the function I'm using to do it:

```vb
Function lastRow(ByVal ShT As Worksheet)
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ShT.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
    lRow = ShT.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
    Do While Application.CountA(ShT.Rows(lRow)) = 0 And lRow <> 1
        lRow = lRow - 1
    Loop
    lastRow = lRow
End Function
```

The first row to insert data is 15 and the last row is 50.

View the code [here](https://pastebin.com/Cr892DuR).

When I press f8 it is here that it gives the error.

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    WebcamHwnd = Me.VideoCamera.[_GethWnd]
    txtData.Value = Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yy h:mm")
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: One problem is that you're using the same name for a variable and a function.  You have a function `fn_lastrow`, but then you're also trying to set the value of the variable `fn_lastrow` in your `CommandButton1_Click` sub.  Try changing the name of the variable or the function.  Then edit your question, and we will have a clearer idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: I changed the function and its still the same thing, it substitutes the data

Comment: Is it always substituting the same row?  Always row 15, for example?  Regardless, your problem seems to be with writing to the new row, so I suggest stepping through your code (press `F8`) to find out why `fn_lastrow` isn't the value you expect it to be.

Comment: Yes it inserts into the same row, i provided the code that is giving me the error into my post

Comment: Your main sub is adding data to columns `B`, `K` and `AC`, but it is always determining the last row by looking _only_ at column `A` - you should be determining the last row by reference to a column where you _know_ that the amount of data is _growing_, i.e. column `B`, `K` or `AC`

Comment: I did that once when i was first trying that, and the thing is if i change  "A:A" to "A:AC" my insert that goes to some cell that i dont know exactly what is it

Comment: "When i press f8 its here that it gives the error" - what is the error message you get?  Do you have your VBA error handling set on "Break in class module"? (Tools > Options > General > Error Trapping)

Comment: Sorry for being away, i already fixed the code thanks to Tim suggestion, thanks to everybody.